# Why isn't usleep working?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, unix, system-calls

I have a function that is being run on a separate queue/thread. In this function I am trying to call `usleep`.

Regardless of the value passed in, `usleep` doesn't seem to work. The same goes for `sleep()`.

To diagnose the error, I printed out `errno`. `errno` prints as: "Interrupted system call"

**What exactly does this mean, and how could I go about diagnosing it?**

The man pages describe the error as:

```
[EINTR]            A signal was delivered to the process and its action was to invoke a signal-catching
                    function.
```

Note I am on OSX Mountain Lion using Xcode 4 and using Objective-C. I am developing an app for OSX using Cocoa.

Answer (score 4):

`usleep` and `sleep` can be interrupted in this manner by the delivery of signals.

There is no dedicated signal delivery thread, so signals can be delivered to arbitrary threads in your application.

**Note** Original answer left below does *not* work properly on Mountain Lion - something else is triggering the EINTR when run under XCode.

To avoid this problem, we swap over to `nanosleep`, and use the fact that when it gets interrupted it returns the remaining time in the second parameter:

```
struct timespec to_sleep = { 1, 0 }; // Sleep for 1 second
while ((nanosleep(&to_sleep, &to_sleep) == -1) && (errno == EINTR));
```

Although, if you're using an NSThread, then you're better off using:

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f]; // sleep for 1 second
```

which is the Cocoa way of sleeping, and does not suffer from the 'hiccuping' that `sleep`, `usleep` and `nanosleep` experience

**Old Answer** - Does not work properly under the debugger.

If you want to prevent the thread that has your `usleep` from being interrupted, you need to mask out all the signals that may be delivered to the thread. e.g.

```
#include <signal.h>

sigset_t sigset;
sigset_t oldset;
sigfillset(&sigset);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, &oldset);
usleep(9999);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldset, NULL);
```

*Note*: No error checking done in this code

Comment: That might work (but I doubt it if it is the debugger), but it doesn't really answer OP's question.   The real issue is *why doesn't it work in the first place*?  It should work.

Comment: Huh, there appears to be 4 interrupts when running under the debugger. Even with the signal blocking code, it just doesn't work. I'll refactor the answer to use the nanosleep trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can't arbitrarily print `errno` at any time and expect it to be useful.  It is a per-thread variable that will only be set after a particular syscall sets it.

I.e. you can only check `errno` when you have determined that a call has failed.

It is highly unlikely that either call is failing.   Exceedingly unlikely.

---

It wasn't clear from your question that you were grabbing the return value.

- Try it outside the debugger, it may be the debugger hosing things w/signals.  If so, it is likely a bug.
- Do you have any other signal heavy code or subsystems in play?   Signal handlers are screwy on Unix systems, in general.
- are you using lldb?  have you tried switching to gdb?

Comment: I am aware of that. However in this case, the call *did* fail. At failure, usleep() returns -1. I checked the returned value; its -1.

Comment: You question, as worded, doesn't indicate that.  Fair enough.

Comment: I tried it outside the debugger but I still get an identical error. I do not have any signal heavy code and I am using gdb.

Comment: OK -- try `usleep()` in `main()` prior to doing anything.  Then try it in a standalone program.  Something *very odd* is going on with signals in your app.