# Sleep() returns early in xcode

Tags: xcode, unix

**If i run this code in xcode ,sleep return when child process exit in just 1 second;but when i make and run this code in terminal,it will sleep 10 seconds;why??**

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  pid_t pid;
  if ((pid = fork()) ==0) {
      sleep(1);
  }else{
      sleep(10);
      printf("hello");
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you checked the return code from sleep you would see it returning `-1` and setting errno to `EINTR`.

Please see answer I posted for working around the issue if you need to use [something akin to sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239866/why-isnt-usleep-working/12243633#12243633).

Comment: My really question is:my same code run in xcode and in terminal show different result.Why?I guess some setting in xcode cause this , but i wonder what is it.

Comment: There's interference because of the debugger. You have to use the `while (nanosleep(...))` trick instead. It's a Mac behaviour that you have to work around if you're putting a sleep into your process early in the startup process. You'll see the same behaviour if you simply run the program under `lldb` at the command line

Answer (score 0):

The function `sleep` will sleep for the desired amount of seconds or until a signal is being sent to the process. ([man sleep](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sleep.3.html))

In this case the signal `SIG_CHLD` is being sent to your program. `SIG_CHLD` is the signal that represents the termination of a child process.

To ignore the signal simply add:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

and dont forget to include `#include<signal.h>`

Adding this line made the program execute correctly on my Mac.

For a more elaborate answer see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7171836/947321

Comment: you haven't understand my question and your code not work in my xcode. 1. SIGCHLD default setting is SIG_IGN ,you do not need signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) ;2. even you set signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) my code in xcode still not work.My really question is:my same code run in xcode and in terminal show different result.Why?I guess some setting in xcode cause this , but i wonder what is it.

Comment: I am using Xcode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008) and http://pastebin.com/9J0wUBBw works like a charm. And the different behaviour should be caused by the attached debugger, I am not certain though.